# Creating Buffer from field in Attribute table

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-desktop, geoprocessing, buffer

I have a shapefile in ArcMap with about 30 polygons and want create an inside buffer, using a different value for the distance of each buffer on each polygon. I was wondering if there was a way to use a field in the  attribute table of that shapefile to created an inside buffer, and if there is a way, how would I specify the units for that field in the attribute table.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a "Distance or Field" parameter in ArcMap's Buffer Tool: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//000800000019000000

To create the "inside" buffer, just use a negative number of the units.