# Buffers with Varying Distances around a Set of Points

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, point, buffer

I have set of points in one shapefile and I have a table with a unique identifier that matches each point. I want to make a buffer around each point, according to the radius that I have specified in the table. Is this possible? I joined the table to the points, but from what I know, the buffer tool doesn't have such an option?

Comment: Related/duplicate: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/77953/creating-buffer-from-field-in-attribute-table?rq=1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using the buffer tool, you should be able to set the buffer to the values in a field. Selecting the 'field' radio button rather than the 'length' option in the Distance section, you can define the buffer width using table values.